# Inserting and updating a block of code at the end of a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, files

So I have a file which looks like the following

```
#ifndef CONFIG_DHCP_H
#define CONFIG_DHCP_H

FILE_LICENCE(GPL2_OR_LATER_OR_UBDL);

#include <config/defaults.h>

#define DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC 1
#define DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC 10
//#define DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC   4   /* as per PXE spec */
//#define DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC 32  /* as per PXE spec */

/*
 * .
 * .
 * .
 */

#define PXEBS_MAX_TIMEOUT_SEC 3
//#define PXEBS_MAX_TIMEOUT_SEC     7   /* as per PXE spec */

#include <config/local/dhcp.h>

#endif /* CONFIG_DHCP_H */
```

It is a lot longer as indicated by the `...` but I highlighted the relevant parts. I need to change it into the following

```
#ifndef CONFIG_DHCP_H
#define CONFIG_DHCP_H

FILE_LICENCE(GPL2_OR_LATER_OR_UBDL);

#include <config/defaults.h>

#define DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC 1
#define DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC 10
//#define DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC   4   /* as per PXE spec */
//#define DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC 32  /* as per PXE spec */

/*
 * .
 * .
 * .
 */

#define PXEBS_MAX_TIMEOUT_SEC 3
//#define PXEBS_MAX_TIMEOUT_SEC     7   /* as per PXE spec */

#include <config/local/dhcp.h>

#undef DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC
#define DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC 4
#undef DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC
#define DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC 32

#endif /* CONFIG_DHCP_H */
```

In other words insert the four lines at the bottom. Note however that the lines are also present earlier in the file and must not be touched. If the lines are present, one should be able to update their values.

My attempt with the testfile at the top saved as `dhcp.h` is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

dhcp="${1:-dhcp.h}"

read -r -d '' dhcp_regex_timeout <<'EOM'
#undef *DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC
#define *DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC *\d+
#undef *DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC
#define *DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC *\d+
EOM

read -r -d '' dhcp_correct_timeout <<EOM
#undef DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC
#define DHCP_DISC_START_TIMEOUT_SEC ${2:-4}
#undef DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC
#define DHCP_DISC_END_TIMEOUT_SEC ${3:-32}
EOM

echo "${dhcp_correct_timeout}"

if grep -Pazoq "${dhcp_regex_timeout}\n+#endif" "${dhcp}"; then
  # The block is present at the end of the file, time to update it
  sed "s/${dhcp_regex_timeout}/${dhcp_correct_timeout}/"
else
  # The block is NOT present at the end of the file, time to insert it
  sed -E "s/\n*\(#endif .*\)/${dhcp_correct_timeout}\n\n\1/"
fi
```

Any suggestions? The code above is merely a sketch and does not work, but it shows what I want to do. I am open for other solutions such as `awk` if that makes it any easier =)

Comment: Since you're just overriding values that may or not have been specified at the top of the file, isn't this exactly what the `#include <config/local/dhcp.h>` line is for - is there a reason not to just keep your updated values in that file?

Answer (score 2):

If the code is not yet present you can use the hold space of `sed` to collect the commented definitions and place them at the end without comment, and undefining them first:

```
sed '\|//#define DHCP_DISC_.*_TIMEOUT_SEC|H;\|include <config/local/dhcp.h>|{G;s/define/undef/g;s/ [0-9][[:print:]]*//g;G;s|//||g;}'
```

So you have this one-pass `sed` command and don't need all that other code. In detail:

- `\|//#define DHCP_DISC_.*_TIMEOUT_SEC|H` will append those lines to the hold space for later use
- `\|include <config/local/dhcp.h>|` matches the line after which the new lines should be placed. All further commands are only executed for this line
- `G` appends the hold space (both saved lines and an empty line that will help us separate the code nicely) to the pattern space
- `s/define/undef/g` is to undefine instead of defining
- `s/ [0-9][[:print:]]*//g` will remove the definition (and comment) for the undefine
- `G` adds the lines again, this time for the redefinition
- `s|//||g` finally removes the comments for all four lines